# OpenLDAP : allow non-rootdn admin to set password of other users

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I can't figure out howto configure a proper ACL in OpenLDAP 2.4 (old slapd.conf approach) which allows a non-rootdn admin to change other users passwords.

I have a simple LDAP structure:

```
    dc=vsp
       |
    dc=mgmt
     |    |
ou=People cn=admin (NOT the rootdn!!)
```

I have the following ACL:

```
access to attrs=userPassword
        by dn="cn=admin,dc=mgmt,dc=vsp" write
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none
access to *
        by dn="cn=admin,dc=mgmt,dc=vsp" write
        by self write
        by * read
```

I have verified the admin password with ldapwhoami - that works.

But changing een other users password fails:

```
[user@host ~]# ldappasswd -H ldap://[a.b.c.d]:389 -x -w xxxxxxxx -D "cn=admin,dc=mgmt,dc=vsp" "uid=jdoe,ou=People,dc=mgmt,dc=vsp" -S
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Result: Insufficient access (50)
```

I am stuck after trying for many hours.

Thanks, John